# Axapta 3.0 creating base64 string from file

Tags: base64, axapta, x++

In later AX versions it's easy to make base64 string from file using .NET components but how to do same thing in AX3.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In AX 4.0 or later you could use [BinData.base64Encode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa878526%28v=ax.10%29.aspx).

In Axapta 3.0 you could interface with [Crypt32.CryptBinaryToString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379887%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

The other way round would be interface with [Crypt32.CryptStringToBinaryA](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380285%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Morten Lehrmann has an implementation [here](http://lehr.dk/dynax.php).